# is Java 8 forEach loop a method like ListIterator or a loop like while and do-loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator

I was reading about topics introduced in Java 8 and came across forEach. It was described as a loop.
It takes argument in the form of lambda expression unlike any other java loop which take boolean expression. Is forEach a method or a loop?

Comment: _"Is it a method or a loop?"_ <- what is _"**it**"_ in this context?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: is forEach a method or a loop?

Comment: It's a method. Whenever you see someObject.something(), something is a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method which, underneath the scenes, provides the [terminal operation of a `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) through a `Consumer`.

It *technically* iterates across the entirety of the stream, but streams aren't really iterable - given an infinite stream, there's no way to prove that iteration has completed or *will* complete.

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare the syntax required to use the different constructs!

You invoke a method, and you pass a parameter. Therefore forEach() is a method call, not a built in language construct.

Comment: thanks. But why do they call it a loop instead of iterator? I always think of a loop as something that is part of the language like while and do-while.

Comment: @kaka - It's called a loop because internally it acts like a loop, repeatedly calling the supplied lambda on each element of the stream as it is encountered. An iterator doesn't do any looping itself; it's a passive state (capturing the current position in the object being iterated over) not a control structure. Calling the `forEach` method an iterator would be a gross distortion of what it does.